# HTML View loses state during search (ajax) update

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have been searching around trying to find a solution to this with no success :(

I have a page that lists products. The page has two layouts (list and grid) with a toggle to switch between the views (basically changing the CSS behind the view) this is all working as expected !

I am using full text search on the page containing of a search box (text input) that filters the products based on the entered search string etc... this is also working as expected.

I have a keyup event listener on the text input so that the data is filtered on each key press using an ajax get response. The data is filtered correctly however the view state / switch is not considered.

E.g. the default view is a list. If I do not change the view and search, everything is updated correctly: the correct results renders as a list. However, if I change to the grid view, and then search, although the results are correct the view is switched back to the original (list) view.

The switch toggle also stops working after a search has passed.

I am not sure, but it seems like the $.get methods response reloads the original file not containing any added classes (in relation to the view change) that have been added. It also appears that all JS added on document load is lost.

This is "basically" what I have:

**CSS**

```
.hideSection {
  display: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/employees" id="employee_search" method="get">
     <input autocomplete="off" id="query" name="query" type="text">
 </form>

 <div class="btn-group">
   <button id="listViewButton" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">LIST</button>
   <button id="gridViewButton" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">GRID</button>
 </div>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="listView" class="list-view">
    ...
</div>
<div id="gridView" class="grid-view hide-view" >
    ...
</div>
```

**JS (CoffeScript)**

```
$("#gridViewButton").click ->
    $(".gridView").removeClass "hideSection"
    $(".listView").addClass "hideSection"

$("#listViewButton").click ->
    $(".listView").removeClass "hideSection"
    $(".gridView").addClass "hideSection"

$("#employee_search input").keyup ->
    $.get $("#employee_search").attr("action"), $("#employee_search").serialize(), null, "script"
    false
```

As said, all searching works as expected, the problem is that the view looses its state (List or Grid) when searching, and additionally all JS appears not to work after the search - im not sure if this is something to do with the response from the $.get method as looking at it in the inspector, it contains the HTML from the original file not the modified file after changing the view etc..

Any help on this in relation to keeping the view state on searching would be greatly appreciated !

Thanks,
Jon.

Answer (score 0):

`listView` and `gridView` are `id` not `class` and use [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass) like,

```
$("#gridViewButton").click ->
    $("#gridView,#listView").toggleClass "hideSection"

$("#listViewButton").click ->
    $("#listView,#gridView").toggleClass "hideSection"
```

Comment: Hi Rohan, thanks for the reply, however this is my bad - I just entered the example code into this post quickly. I am actually referencing the ids using "#listView","#gridView" and this is working as expected so I assume is not the problem !? - I will look into the toggleClass too ! thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way I managed to achieve my required behavior was to modify the Ajax GET method, by adding a success handler and modifying DOM data within this handler:

Within my keyup handler, before the GET, I save the current view state (styles added to the view containers) in variables accordingly. Within the GET, in the success handler I modify the result setting the view (styles) to the the new (changed) values (form the set variables) after the DOM was loaded:

```
$("#employee_search input").keyup (event) ->
  alteredListViewHtml = $(".listViewEmployeeContainer").attr("class")
  alteredGridViewHtml = $(".gridViewEmployeeContainer").attr("class")

  $.get $("#employee_search").attr("action"), $("#employee_search").serialize(), ((result) ->
    $(".listViewEmployeeContainer").attr('class', alteredListViewHtml)
    $(".gridViewEmployeeContainer").attr('class', alteredGridViewHtml)
    viewToggleClickHandlers()
    return ), "script"

  false
```

I hope this makes sense and can help someone out !

Cheers,
Jon.